# Moving to Australia. Do I need to declare personal electronics?

Tags: immigration, australia, customs

I'm moving to Australia later this year. Some of my personal items (laptop, tablet etc) will be packed in my luggage. Do I need to declare these at customs on my incoming passenger card? They're all years old.

I assume this isn't just the case for electronics if it's required, but all my suitcase / hand luggage items will have been purchased overseas. Would they really expect you to declare every single item of your luggage?

Comment: How long do you expect to remain in Australia?

Comment: I would not expect electronics to be special, but I would expect some sort of customs declaration to be required if you are relocating.  I have had to do this moving DE->CH, and my son had to do it moving DE->UK.  I suggest looking at the AU customs website.

Comment: I intend to remain there forever

Comment: Can't answer either way but have a look at https://www.abf.gov.au/entering-and-leaving-australia/duty-free and https://www.abf.gov.au/buying-online/buying-online

Comment: If your electronics are years old then it seems you won't have to pay duties or tax on them. Maybe contact Border Force?